# protect json data in an amazon bucket

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-s3

Hypothesis:
I have some json file in an amazon s3 bucket.
In the same bucket I have a html-js viewev that uses that json files as data source.

I'd like that a user could only see data using my html-js viewer and not, for example, downlading the json files locally or using a 3rd party viewer.

Is there any possibility to achieve such objective?

Comment: The page runs on the browser, so the permissions would therefore need to be set public.

Comment: The reason is that, since I provide the data, I would like the user to see my advertisement, not that of a 3rd party thief (even if robin hood)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with only browser side code served by a static s3 bucket. No matter how hard you obfuscate or encrypt the data, you still have to provide the code to unlock and display it.

The only way you can (more or less) ensure they have to view your advertisement is to serve up the HTML of the viewer itself. It sounds like this JSON isn't changing much, if you're just serving it out of an s3 bucket. You can probably just pre-render the HTML with your advertisement and put that in the s3 bucket, rather than having json + an html viewer.